# Apache: fall through to controller if matching file not found

Tags: apache-2.2

We have a Perl based web site that runs under Apache with mod_perl.  At its core are a large number of individual Perl scripts - one per page.  For example:

www.example.com/index.pl
www.example.com/account.pl
www.example.com/login.pl

We are slowly refactoring it and moving towards a controlled based model where we have a single point of entry - a dispatcher.  The current approach is to replace the code in each page script with a call to the controller as it is refactored.  This leaves us with lots of stub scripts that all do the same thing.  Is there a way to tell Apache to look for a matching file first, and if that fails, call the controller code and pass it the request URI?

Answer (score 0):

Look up **mod_rewrite**. Put something like the below in a **.htaccess** file in the appropriate directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /controller.pl?request=$1 [L]
```

The second line is a conditional check **!-f** which proceeds to the next line **if the file does not exist**. You'll need to adjust the third line to go the correct path and pass in the appropriate parameters.